# Ansible 2.9.10 Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am having trouble understanding the problem with this code attached.
I am trying to apply these actions on 3 AWS servers, working and the `ssh` connection works properly.
Also- there seems to be an issue with a lot of the answers online as a lot of them are still using Ansible 1.9 and the syntax is completely different.
Attaching the code (playbook):

```
---
- hosts:  lb_servers
  name: Configure load balance servers
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: nginx_lb

- hosts:  web_servers
  name: Configure web servers
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: tomcat

- hosts:  db_servers
  name: Configure database servers
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: mongodb
```

Attached is also a snapshot of the error message.

Thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: Please do not post code, commands or error messages as images. It is usually hardly readable and it impairs the search engine ability to index them. This is specifically pointed out as a bad practice in [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator Gotcha.

Comment: Are you running this playbook as root on the target machine ? (with either `remote_user: root` or `become: true`)

Comment: @Zeitounator Don't know exactly what you mean.
I saw similar notes and answers involving what yu wrote but I am not sure where to insert this code.

Comment: Ok I Inserted the ```become: true``` inside my playbook, and run it again. Now the process is stuck in the task, but without failures. But- it is really stuck and not moving.

Answer (score 0):

If "Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation" happens for all nodes except one,
check if **controlpath** is set unique per host or not in **ansible.cfg**

use the control path similar to following to make it unique per host, port and user combination

```
[ssh_connection]
#...
control_path = /dev/shm/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
```

Alternatively,  set the environment variable :

```
export ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH=/dev/shm/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
```

For more details, about this configuration run

```
ansible-config list | grep -B 8 -A 5 ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH$
```

So this is what they are saying :

> description:
>
> - This is the location to save ssh's ControlPath sockets, it uses ssh's variable
>   substitution.
> - Since 2.3, if null, ansible will generate a unique hash. Use `%(directory)s` to
>   indicate where to use the control dir path setting.
> - Before 2.3 it defaulted to `control_path=%(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r`.
> - Be aware that this setting is ignored if `-o ControlPath` is set in ssh args.   env:
> - name: ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH   ini:
> - key: control_path
>   section: ssh_connection   yaml:
>   key: ssh_connection.control_path